# C# to SQL Server on client's network

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I have a client with an established accounting database for which I want to write a report.  I am planning to use VS 2008.  I have no difficulty doing this for SQL Server running on my own machine but want to know how best to publish a c# program to run on the client's network SQL Server.  So there are two main issues:
1.) How to adapt the connection string for the remote environment?
2.) A recommendation for good remote assistance method for a fledgling contractor working on someone else's network.

Answer (score 1):

Store the connection string in a configuration file (Visual Studio will do this for you most of the time now) and just adjust it when you deploy the app on the client's network.

Remote Assistance Method - check out Microsoft SharedView, and if you want to pay for a higher-end solution, LogMeIn Rescue. Edit - Also, check out TeamViewer (www.teamviewer.com).

Additional Information on Remote Clients:

**SharedView** - http://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=94 - Free, requires Windows Live ID, up to 15 people can watch a screen and you can change presenters at any time.

**TeamViewer** - http://www.teamviewer.com - Free (and / or pay version) - Start up in "Remote Support", "Presenter", "File Transfer", or "VPN" mode. Can switch sides with partner easily. (Warning - I've had issues with using this in Vista with the UAC command prompts).

**LogMeIn Rescue** - http://www.logmein.com - Pay Product (expensive but extremely nice tool for professional client support). One-way (can't change sides with customer).

Comment: Will the client need to pay for and install these remote assistance methods?  I can pay for a product but I don't think I can ask my client(s).

Comment: I gave you a variety, none of which require clients to buy anything. SharedView is free and must be installed, TeamViewer is free and they just have to launch the client module, and LogMeIn Rescue you pay for but they just launch the client module.

Comment: (One other note, SharedView requires a Windows Live ID / passport.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of a connection string to connect clients SqlServer :

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

For more connection strings [click here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

I think you know that but I want to mention you should keep it in your web.config. You may need to deploy your product to clients network. then it will be easy to configure your application.

Hope this helps !

Comment: So edit MyProg.exe.config.deploy  Or is there a better way to create a config file?

I am doing WinForm application for which I created a dummy database.  When I Publish there isn't an option to avoid publishing the DB.

Comment: MyProg.exe.config is ok. You don't need any other config file. published db is good for testing. but when you need to configure your application to clients db you will change only connection string at config file and delete the test db. I hope I understand you correctly.